# LocalBroadcastManager anternative?

Tags: java, android

In mainAcitivity, I receive data about the current gps position (lat, lon) from the socket BLE (gps module). I want to pass them to a fragment from google maps. I want the maps fragment to know about the new coordinates only when new data is received. LocalBroadcastManager was a good solution for me, I know it is "deprecated" what could be a safe alternative?

Comment: RxJava's `PublishSubject`, Kotlin's coroutines (e.g., `BroadcastChannel` or `StateFlow`), and `LiveData` would be three possibilities.

Comment: I'd use LiveData, as @CommonsWare suggested!

Comment: I prefer to keep using `LocalBroadcastManager` as long as it's available. It's a convenient tool and I think Google shouldn't have deprecated it.